# how to identify Label control in for each Silverlight Datagrid

Tags: datagrid, silverlight-4.0

how to identify label control in foreach Silverlight Datagrid

For Each item In TaskDataGrid.ItemsSource

TryCast(TryCast(item, StackPanel).Children(2), Label).Content = "New Text"

Next

I have label control in 2 nd Column how to identify and assign the  value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working fine..

```
For Each rowItem In TaskDataGrid.ItemsSource 
            ' Ensures that all rows are loaded. 
            TaskDataGrid.ScrollIntoView(rowItem, TaskDataGrid.Columns.Last())  
            Dim fe As FrameworkElement = TaskDataGrid.Columns(2).GetCellContent(rowItem)
            Dim fe1 As FrameworkElement = TaskDataGrid.Columns(1).GetCellContent(rowItem)

            Dim gridCmbo As Grid = DirectCast(fe, Grid)

            Dim gridCmbo1 As Grid = DirectCast(fe1, Grid)

            Dim lbltaskId As Label = CType(gridCmbo1.FindName("lbltaskId"), Label)

            Dim lblBaseReceipt As Label = CType(gridCmbo.FindName("lblBaseReceipt"), Label)


        Next
```